# how do i check is it safe for writing in c++

Tags: c++, file, space, disk

in this function where i am trying to write something on a disk, how can i check if the part of the disk is empty and it's safe to write on that part so i wouldn't lose data.

i tried finding answer to this and saw peek function but it seems that it's not working with that, I get an error with it

```
void write_sector(int num){
    char diskName[] = "/dev/sda";                                       //disk name
    std::ofstream disk(diskName, std::ios_base::binary);                //opening the disk for output
    std::string diskError = std::string() + diskName + ": ";

    if(!disk){
    throw(std::runtime_error(diskError + std::strerror(errno)));
    }

    disk.seekp(512 * num);                                              //changing position to specific sector

    if(!disk){
    throw(std::runtime_error(diskError + std::strerror(errno)));
    }
    

    disk << "MAGIC";                                                    //writing in sector

    if(!disk){
    throw(std::runtime_error(diskError + std::strerror(errno)));
    }
    
    disk.close();
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to write directly to the disk? Wouldn't writing to a file be much better?

Comment: client said that i should open hard drive on a sector level and write something in an empty sector

Comment: If you have managed to open the disk as described above, the disk should have no file system. So, any sector would be fair game, since your application (or your client's) application manages the drive.  If it is a drive with a file system, then you need to get the free sectors list from the drive, the way to do this depends entirely on the filesystem in question.

Comment: Can I be frank? If you are attempting to do sector level writes and you don't really know what you are doing then the potential for significant data loss is unacceptably high. So this is when professional standards should kick in and you should inform one of your managers that you are not confident in your ability to write the code that this client requires.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.